# MVC Application call a web service with client certificate

Tags: web, service, client, ssl-certificate

I have a MVC 4.0 application with a web service as reference. The web service is installed on third party remote server will SSL. Also the web service requires client certificate authentication. I installed the certificate that issued by the 3rd party to our test server on Personal store, Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and Third-Party Root Certificate Authorities. Same to my local computer. The application is able to access the remote server and get response on my local development server, but always failed on our test server. Our test server is win 2003 and IIS 6.0. The error I got is "Client Certificate Required". It looks like the remote server either reject or cannot take the certificate we pass.

Here is my code:

```
  var svc = new webservcie();
   svc.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("c:\clientcert.cer"));
   svc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
   svc.url = "https://www.thirdparty.com/WMServices";
   svc.givemedata()
```

I have tried many ways to fix this issue, but cannot. I think the issue is that our test server is not able to access the client certification. I read an article about grant Networkservice access to the certificate, but not sure if it is right or not.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found more detail error from server application event log:

Failed auto update retrieval of third-party root list sequence number from: http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootseq.txt with error: This network connection does not exist.

Thanks!

Comment: After I uncheck the "Update Root Certificate", this error is gone. But I still got this error "The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."